# JSON decoder is failingfor html tags

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a model class like below

```
 Class Person {

   let name : String

}
```

API returns name as "Text Area
Section
     **Heading**

Bullet points "` including the html tags. however, whenever I am trying to use the jsondecoder i get the below error

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Can someone suggest to me how to decode the string which contains the HTML tags in SwiftUI.

API response:-

```
“Person”: [
      {
        "id”:12345,
        "name": "<div>Text Area</div><div><br></div><div>Section</div><div><br></div><div>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<u><b>Heading</b></u></div><div><ol><li><u>Bullet points&nbsp;"
      }
]
```

Decoder process:

```
func decoder<T:Decodable>(_data: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder() 
  return Just(data) 
     .decode(type: T.self, decoder: decoder) 
     .mapError { error in print(error.localizedDescription)
       return APIServiceError.parseError(error) } 
     .eraseToAnyPublisher() } 
}
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        
      
      
      return Just(data)
        .decode(type: T.self, decoder: decoder)
        .mapError { error in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return APIServiceError.parseError(error)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

Comment: I have confirmed that if i remove the name object in my model class then the decoder works perfectly fine.

Comment: update it in question, not in comments. So that everybody can see it

Comment: also share your complete JSON Response

Comment: “Person”: [
      {
        "id”:12345,
        "name": "<div>Testing<ul>line</ul></div>",
      }
]

Comment: Why is there a comma before the closing bracket? I don’t think that’s valid JSON

Comment: **Never** print `error.localizedDescription`in a `Decodable` context. It shows the meaningless message you got. Print always the `error` instance.

Answer (score 1):

The *JSON* that you provided is not valid. It must be in the below format instead.

```
{"Person":[{"id":12345,"name":"<div>Testing<ul>line</ul></div>"}]}
```

For the above *JSON*, create the following **models**,

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let person: [Person]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case person = "Person"
    }
}

struct Person: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

Now, **parse** the *JSON* like,

```
do {
    let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(model.person.first?.name) //"<div>Testing<ul>line</ul></div>"
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: My bad, I have updated the contents now correctly for the API response. I think I parsing it correcting the way you have suggested but unfortunately it still the same.

Comment: What are you getting after accessing `model.person.first?.name`?

Comment: I get the error as data couldnt be read because of the format as soon as the decoder function executes.

Comment: Have you tried copy pasting the same JSON from the answer and using the same parsing code? It is working fine at my end.

Comment: I didn't as i don't see any difference between the one you are suggesting vs what i have done for the decoder line. one observation what i have made is if i receive this from my api "<div>Text area</div>" then everything works fine. however, as soon as you have the complex HTML tags it fails out. can you try putting HTML tags from the  question and check if works for you.

Comment: In the question, you've added "note" as the key. Please clarify if it is name or note.

Comment: Also, instead of using your code, add the JSON and code that I've added and see if it works. There might be some small mistake.

Comment: Thanks, looks like some one changed the API structure and due to which it was failing. I just conformed with the updated structure and it works now irrespective whatever HTML tags.